# I have a keyword and cipher text but cannot decode it please help!

Tags: encryption

coded text:  ij gj hnev xudmyx hn igim umif obaxidyw kxzq si

the key is JULIET, but i cannot figure out how it is used. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

"you actually solved my riddle good job you win"

How to:

First determine the key word number sequence by taking the key word and assigning each letter its position in the true alphabet:

```
J  U  L  I  E  T
10 21 12 9  5  20
```

Then take the encrypted message and assigned each letter a number by repeating the key word number sequence:

```
I  J  G  J  H  N  E  V  X  U  D  M  Y  X  H  N  I  G  I  M  U  M  I  F  O  B  A  X  I  D  Y  W  K  X  Z  Q  S  I
10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21
```

Finally, take the true alphabet position of each encrypted letter, subtract the assigned value and reveal the position of the true letter:

```
I = 9 (true alphabet position)
  - 10 (assigned key word sequence number)
  = 25 (Not -1, because when you reach the beginning of the alphabet, start counting back from 26)
```

25 is the postion of the true letter which is the letter Y.

```
I  J  G  J  H  N  E  V  X  U  D  M  Y  X  H  N  I  G  I  M  U  M  I  F  O  B  A  X  I  D  Y  W  K  X  Z  Q  S  I
10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21 12 9  5  20 10 21
Y  O  U  A  C  T  U  A  L  L  Y  S  O  L  V  E  D  M  Y  R  I  D  D  L  E  G  O  O  D  J  O  B  Y  O  U  W  I  N
```

Comment: To encrypt the message, the simply added the assigned value, instead of subtracting it.